# Calling tableView.scrollToRow triggers infinite loop when large/accessible text is enabled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I've a TableViewController which utilises Cells that have a CollectionView within them. This works fine until I enable accessibility and set the text really large. The app then gets stuck in an infinite loop.

The solutions I've found online involving the warning in the console mostly involve silencing the warning as it's apparently harmless. When I set a breakpoint for `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes` I'm brought to the TableViewController for the cells with embedded CollectionViews. When I attempt to modify the size of the CollectionView in `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` the function is never called.

Why is this crash happening and what can I do to prevent it?

**Crashing Function**

```
    /**
 This function triggers the refreshing of the table view's last row when the data source was updated.
 We assume only the last row ever changes.

 It then prompts the table view to scroll to its last cell.
 **/
fileprivate func updateLastRow() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let lastIndexPath = IndexPath(row: self.currentSteps.count - 1, section: 0)

        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [lastIndexPath], with: .none)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()

        self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.adjustInsets()
        //We never leave the below function.
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: lastIndexPath,
                                   at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom,
                                   animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Console Output:** (This output is looped indefinitely until XCode crashes)

```
2018-05-01 11:34:43.476977+0200 TestApp[6751:151048] Please check the values returned by the delegate.
2018-05-01 11:34:43.477183+0200 TestApp[6751:151048] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <TestApp.OnboardingChatActionCollectionViewController: 0x7f9ee023ff30>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7f9ede16ce00; frame = (28 1442.5; 291 68); clipsToBounds = YES; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000002582d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000432a00>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {291, 58}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}> collection view layout: <TestApp.OnboardingChatActionCollectionViewController: 0x7f9ee023ff30>.
2018-05-01 11:34:43.477294+0200 TestApp[6751:151048] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
2018-05-01 11:34:43.477500+0200 TestApp[6751:151048] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2018-05-01 11:34:43.477665+0200 TestApp[6751:151048] the item width must be less than the width of the UICollectionView minus the section insets left and right values, minus the content insets left and right values.
```

**CollectionViewController**

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "ChatActionButtonCell"

/// ViewController for managing chat action buttons
class OnboardingChatActionCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var onboardingCellDelegate: BaseOnboardingTableViewCell?


    /// This will link a UICollectionView to this controller
    func attach(toCollection collection: UICollectionView) {
        collection.delegate = self
        collection.dataSource = self
        collection.collectionViewLayout = self

        collection.contentInset.left = 0
        collection.contentInset.right = 0

        collection.backgroundColor = .clear

        self.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 29)


        collection.register(UINib(nibName: "ChatActionButton", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ChatActionButtonCell")
    }


    /// Renders buttons inactive and greys them out (based on user selection) after an action was tapped
    fileprivate func greyOutButtons(selectedCell: OnboardingChatActionCollectionViewCell) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let cells = self.collectionView?.visibleCells as! [OnboardingChatActionCollectionViewCell]

            for cell in cells {
                if cell == selectedCell {
                    cell.background.backgroundColor = .charcoalGrey
                } else {
                    cell.background.backgroundColor = .aqua10
                    cell.actionButton.setTitleColor(.gunmetal, for: .normal)
                }

                cell.actionButton.isEnabled = false
            }
        }
    }


    /// Wrapping buttons on a new row if they're too large
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)

        var leftMargin = sectionInset.left
        var maxY: CGFloat = -1.0
        attributes?.forEach { layoutAttribute in
            if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.y >= maxY {
                leftMargin = sectionInset.left
            }

            layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x = leftMargin

            leftMargin += layoutAttribute.frame.width + minimumInteritemSpacing
            maxY = max(layoutAttribute.frame.maxY , maxY)
        }

        return attributes
    }


    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return onboardingCellDelegate?.onboardingStep.chatActions?.count ?? 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let chatActionCell = self.collectionView?.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ChatActionButtonCell", for: indexPath) as! OnboardingChatActionCollectionViewCell

        chatActionCell.chatAction = onboardingCellDelegate?.onboardingStep.chatActions?[indexPath.row]

        chatActionCell.background.layer.cornerRadius = chatActionCell.background.frame.height / 2
        chatActionCell.sizeToFit()

        chatActionCell.collectionControllerDelegate = self

        return chatActionCell
    }
}
```

**How the TableView appears without enlarged text** (nothing loads when larger text is enabled)

[image]